# REST services work from curl, not from application

Tags: javascript, spring, rest

I have a small web app built using Spring, and the REST services are accessible from curl and postman. If I try to access them using the JavaScript hosted on my web app I get a 405 error. What could cause this?

I realize there are insecurities in the code, this is just a rushed class project so they are not important.

If I copy the JavaScript code and run it in the console of the browser it works.
User class

```
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;


public class User {

    @Id
    public String id;



    private String username;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String password;
    private int zipCode;
    private int jacketThreshold;
    private int coatThreshold;



    public User() {}

    public User(String username)
    {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public User(String firstName, String lastName, String password) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public User(String username, String password, int zipCode) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.zipCode = zipCode;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public int getZipCode() {
        return zipCode;
    }

    public void setZipCode(int zipCode) {
        this.zipCode = zipCode;
    }

    public int getJacketThreshold() {
        return jacketThreshold;
    }

    public void setJacketThreshold(int jacketThreshold) {
        this.jacketThreshold = jacketThreshold;
    }

    public int getCoatThreshold() {
        return coatThreshold;
    }

    public void setCoatThreshold(int coatThreshold) {
        this.coatThreshold = coatThreshold;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format(
                "User[id=%s, firstName='%s', lastName='%s']",
                id, firstName, lastName);
    }

}
```

UserController class

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@RestController
public class UserController {
    private final UserRepository repository;

    public UserController(UserRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    @CrossOrigin
    @PostMapping("/newuser")
    User newUser(@RequestBody User newUser)
    {
        return repository.save(newUser);
    }
}
```

UserRepository

```
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource;

@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "users", path = "users")
public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User, String> {

    public User findByUsername(@Param("username") String username);

}
```

Application class

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class WtwApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WtwApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

JavaScript calling the REST service

```
var user = document.getElementById('uname');
var pass = document.getElementById('pass');
var zip = document.getElementById('zip');
const data = { username : user, password : pass};
fetch('http://localhost:8080/newuser', {
    method: 'POST', // or 'PUT'
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        console.log('Success:', data);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error:', error);
    });
```

Error received

```
2020-12-04 22:52:34.071  WARN 17936 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported]
```

Comment: please share some codes

Comment: plese share the exception from your javascript code. I am guessing there might be some cors issue.

Answer (score 0):

Cross origin must include your js hosted server address like
Ex - @CrossOrigin(origins="http://localhost:3000)
and add it after the @RestController

Comment: That does not work, but it does stop Postman from working

Answer (score 0):

Check your js code.
If you look at your controller, it's declared @PostMapping. Make sure your js code is calling the same POST method.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are returning a @ResponseBody or a @ResponseStatus

To fix this simply add a @ResponseBody

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/user", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String updateUser(@RequestBody User user){
    return userService.updateUser(user).getId();
}
```

or a @ResponseStatus to your method.

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/user", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.OK)
public String updateUser(@RequestBody User user){
    return userService.updateUser(user).getId();
}
```

Comment: Both result in the same error, 'Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported]'

Comment: Found a Typo in your URL  URL Used by you : fetch('http://localhost:8080/newuser"' , Correct URL : fetch('http://localhost:8080/newuser'. There are extra quotes check it out

Comment: Fixed the typo, same issue.

Comment: Request is not landing your controller itself right ?